# Fitting circuitikz labels into boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, fit

I tried to draw an equivalent circuit for a resistor using the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductor]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(left)
    to[R=$R$, name=r] ++(2,0)
    to[L=$L$,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(right)
    to[short] ++(2,0)

    (left) to[short] ++(0,1)
    to[C=$C$, name=c] ($(right)+(0,1)$)
    to[short] (right)

    node[fit=(left)(right)(c)(r),draw, dashed, label={Resistor}, inner sep=10pt]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This resulted in:

[image: Imgur]

Fit does not take the "C" label above the capacitor into account.
I fixed this by putting an additional coordiate above the capacitor:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductor]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(left)
    to[R=$R$, name=r] ++(2,0)
    to[L=$L$,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(right)
    to[short] ++(2,0)

    (left) to[short] ++(0,1)
    to[C=$C$, name=c] ($(right)+(0,1)$)
    to[short] (right)

    coordinate[above=10pt of c] (top)
    node[fit=(left)(right)(top)(r),draw, dashed, label={Resistor},
    inner sep=10pt] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which looks reasonable:

[image: Imgur]

Is there a better way to tell fit that it should also fit the "C" label above the capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

As you are already loading `calc` tikzlibrary, you can use it to *modify* `c` coordinate inside `fit`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductor]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(left)
    to[R=$R$, name=r] ++(2,0)
    to[L=$L$,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(right)
    to[short] ++(2,0)

    (left) to[short] ++(0,1)
    to[C=$C$, name=c] ($(right)+(0,1)$)
    to[short] (right)

    node[fit={(left)(right)($(c.north)+(0,.5)$)(r)},draw, dashed, label={Resistor},
    inner sep=10pt] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]